# Ingresar iconos en WordPress desde css

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Estoy tratando de ingresar iconos de FontAwesome en mi plantilla de WordPress pero al momento en que veo la plantilla en el explorador, estos no se muestran

en mi css los coloco de la siguiente manera:

```
nav.sociales li a[href*="facebook.com"]::before {
    content: '\f09a';
}
nav.sociales li a[href*="youtube.com"]::before {
    content: '\f16a';
}
nav.sociales li a[href*="instagram.com"]::before {
    content: '\f16d';
}
```

en mi archivo functions.php:

```
wp_register_style('fotawesome', get_template_directory_uri() . 'css/font-awesome.min.css', array('normalize'), '4.7.0');
```

y asi es como se muestran

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

le di a inspeccionar elemento por si habia un error que me mostrara en la consola,pero esta no me marca nada, alguien me puededecir cual es mi error?

**Parte en la que se muestran los iconos**

```
<!-- Inicio Redes Sociales -->
        <div class="informacion-encabezado">
            <div class="redes-sociales">
                <?php 
                    $args = array(
                        'theme_location' => 'social-menu',
                        'container' => 'nav',
                        'container_class' => 'sociales',
                        'container_id' => 'sociales',
                        'link_before' => '<span class="sr-text">',
                        'link_after' => '</span>'
                    );
                    wp_nav_menu($args);             
                ?>
            </div>
    <!-- Final Redes Sociales -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que cambiarlo por:

```
nav.sociales li a[href*="instagram.com"] i::before {
    content: '\f16d';
}
```

Ya que `i` es utilizado para mostrar los iconos:

*After you get up and running, you can place Font Awesome icons just about anywhere with the `<i>` tag.*

Fuente: http://fontawesome.io

Comment: lo hice como me indicaste, pero aun asi no se mostraron los iconos

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el css y html correspondiente a la parte en la que se muestran los iconos?

Comment: he colocado la parte en la que se muestran los iconos y la parte del css es la que coloque

Comment: Pero en que parte usas la etiqueta `<i>` como en este ejemplo: `<i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

Comment: lo toma automaticamente de la manera en que lo intento realizar o al menos eso deberia hacer

Comment: el error estaba en functions, me faltaba agregarle una barra / para que pudiera tomar la ruta correctamente